Why is the gradient wrt input zero?
This snippet tries to take gradient wrt the input to a trained model
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

DATASET_SIZE = 10
TUNING_EPOCH = 10
RANDOMIZATION = "rand"
shape = (10000,)
bsize = 1
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

input = eval(f"torch.{RANDOMIZATION}")(bsize, *shape).to(device).requires_grad_()
numel = input.numel()
model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Flatten(),
    nn.Linear(numel, numel//2),
    nn.Tanh(),
    nn.Linear(numel//2, 1)
).to(device)
model_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([input])
dataset = [(eval(f"torch.{RANDOMIZATION}_like")(input), (torch.rand(bsize,1)+8).to(device)) for i in range(DATASET_SIZE)]

model.train()
for e in range(TUNING_EPOCH):
    for x, y in dataset:
        model_optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(x)
        loss = torch.nn.MSELoss()(output, y)
        loss.backward(inputs=list(model.parameters()))
        model_optimizer.step()

model.eval()
optimizer.zero_grad()
output = model(input)
output.backward(inputs=input)
print("\ninput.grad", input.grad)

The gradient input.grad, however, is all 0. There are 3 individual fixes

set TUNING_EPOCH = 0, i.e. not training the model
set RANDOMIZATION = "randn", i.e. a different input distribution
set shape = (1000,), making the input smaller

Why would these three changes individually fix the zero gradient issue?

The issue is caused by the Tanh activation.
If you look at the outputs of the Tanh activation after training, you can see the values saturate at 1 or -1 for all activations. This results in gradients vanishing and rounding to zero.
If you change nn.Tanh to nn.ReLU you will see nonzero gradient values.
